# RenderView execute a query

Tags: jsf

Does anyone know why when you try to render a JSF view executes a database query?

I am listing a large paged list, as I have seen on:

http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/WorkingWithLargeTables

I return data list it correctly (with the number of items I want), but I noticed that the RenderView run a query that gets all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF does not do that. It's your own wrong code who does that. You're executing a SQL query in a getter method. Just do not do business job in getter method. Do it in (post)constructor or (action)listener method instead.

#### See also:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)